# Manual back prop using numpy not getting me good results

Tags: numpy, backpropagation

```
import numpy as np
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
def derivative_sigmoid(z):
    return sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))
weights = []
dweights = []
bias = []
dbias = []
z = []
dz = []
act = []
dact = []
lr = 0.001
input_shape = 6
output_shape = 2
shapes = [input_shape] + [400, 400, 400] + [output_shape]
x=np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0],
              [0,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1],
              [1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0]])
y=np.array([[1],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[0],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],
            [1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1]]).ravel()
batch_size=len(x)
for i in range(len(shapes)-1):
    weights.append(np.random.randn(shapes[i], shapes[i+1]))
    bias.append(np.zeros(shapes[i+1]))
    dweights.append(np.zeros_like(weights[i]))
    dbias.append(np.zeros_like(bias[i]))
    z.append(np.zeros((batch_size, shapes[i+1])))
    dz.append(np.zeros((batch_size, shapes[i+1])))
    act.append(np.zeros((batch_size, shapes[i+1])))
    dact.append(np.zeros((batch_size, shapes[i+1])))
for i in range(1000):
    z[0] = x @ weights[0] + bias[0]
    act[0] = sigmoid(z[0])
    z[1] = act[0] @ weights[1] + bias[1]
    act[1] = sigmoid(z[1])
    z[2] = act[1] @ weights[2] + bias[2]
    act[2] = sigmoid(z[2])
    z[3] = act[2] @ weights[3] + bias[3]
    act[3] = sigmoid(z[3])
    
    logits = act[3]
    logits_max = logits.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    norm_logits = logits - logits_max
    counts = np.exp(norm_logits)
    counts_sum = counts.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    counts_sum_inv = counts_sum**-1
    probs = counts * counts_sum_inv
    logprobs = np.log(probs)
    cost = -logprobs[np.arange(batch_size), y].mean()
    
    if i % 100 == 0 or i == 999:
        print(f'At step {i}: cost is {cost}')
    
    dlogprobs = np.zeros_like(probs)
    dlogprobs[np.arange(batch_size), y] = -1/batch_size
    dprobs = (1/probs) * dlogprobs
    dcounts = counts_sum_inv * dprobs
    dcounts_sum_inv = (dcounts * dprobs).sum(1, keepdims=True)
    dcounts_sum = (-counts_sum**-2) * dcounts_sum_inv
    dcounts += np.ones_like(counts) * dcounts_sum
    dnorm_logits = counts * dcounts
    dlogits = dnorm_logits.copy()
    dlogits_max = -dnorm_logits.sum(1, keepdims=True)
    indices = logits.argmax(axis=1)
    num_classes = logits.shape[1]
    one_hot = np.zeros((batch_size, num_classes))
    one_hot[np.arange(len(indices)), indices] = 1
    dlogits += one_hot * dlogits_max
    
    dact[3] = dlogits 
    
    dz[3] = derivative_sigmoid(z[3]) * dact[3]
    dact[2] = dz[3] @ weights[3].T
    dweights[3] = act[2].T @ dz[3]
    dbias[3] = dz[3].sum(axis=0)
    
    dz[2] = derivative_sigmoid(z[2]) * dact[2]
    dact[1] = dz[2] @ weights[2].T
    dweights[2] = act[1].T @ dz[2]
    dbias[2] = dz[2].sum(axis=0)

    dz[1] = derivative_sigmoid(z[1]) * dact[1]
    dact[0] = dz[1] @ weights[1].T
    dweights[1] = act[0].T @ dz[1]
    dbias[1] = dz[1].sum(axis=0)

    dz[0] = derivative_sigmoid(z[0]) * dact[0]
    dweights[0] = x.T @ dz[0]
    dbias[0] = dz[0].sum(axis=0)
    
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        weights[i] -= lr * dweights[i]
        bias[i] -= lr * dbias[i]
print(cost)
```

I am attempting to perform manual back prop through a MLP using only numpy. However, my implementation is not working properly. The cost function is not decreasing by much and then starts to increase so there is obviously some mathematical error in the code. Could you please tell me where my mistake is? I am getting no runtime errors and I tried debugging the code but finding a mistake in matrices can be difficult. I cant find any more mistakes just due to the fact that i don't know if its an implementation or calculation issue.

I tried debugging through the code and fixed some mistakes but cant find any more mistakes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.